# Number of subsequences in a string

Tags: permutations

I know this might be one of the silliest questions out there but I'm going ahead and ask it here since I've lost practice in mathematics.

I have been reading that the number of subsequences in a string is $2^x$ where $x$ is the length of the string and I have also worked some examples which agree with this, however I still am not very comfortable with this explanation. Can somebody formally prove this in simple terms please? More specifically where does the $2$ come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In constructing a subsequence, each element may be present or absent.  That gives two choices for each.  As there are $x$ choices, you multiply that many $2$'s together.  It is the same as finding the number of subsets of a set, the order carries over from the original sequence to the subsequence. As an example, take the sequence $1,2,3$ and try to find all the subsequences by hand.  You should find $2^3=8$ of them.  Each corresponds to one of the binary numbers from $000$ to $111$, where a $0$ says that element is not present in the subsequence and a $1$ says it is.

Comment: Nice! It was not clear for me that $1, 3$ is consider a subsequence. http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Subsequence

Comment: @EduardoReis:  yes, it is.  Sometimes we speak of contiguous subsequences which are required not to have gaps in them, but a general subsequence can.

Comment: @RossMillikan So the total number of subsequences in a string is $2^n$, where $n$ is the length of the string. Wikipidea (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) seems to wrongly say that `The list of all subsequences for the word "apple" would be "a", "ap", "al", "ae", "app", "apl", "ape", "ale", "appl", "appe", "aple", "apple", "p", "pp", "pl", "pe", "ppl", "ppe", "ple", "pple", "l", "le", "e", "".`, because this would only be the list of the **unique** subsequences (24), while for the word `apple`, **all** the subsequences will be 32 (as `p` appears twice in the string). Correct?

Comment: @user3019105: $2^n$ assumes the elements of the sequence are distinct.  In the Wikipedia case, the two $p$s in apple ruin that because if you just take one $p$ you can't tell if it is the first or the second.  $pp$ has only three subsequences, not four.  The other three letters multiply that by $8$ to get $24$.